# Floyd Rose detuning after the first dive-bomb past dropD and can't recover E tuning on the adjustments without unlocking WHY

Tags: guitar, tuning, bridge

I have a Jackson js32 roads special. I get it in E tuning Lock it down and after the first dive bomb it knocks out of tune so far I can't get it back without unlocking it WHY someone please help

Comment: Not sure if it's the case for you but I looked up the guitar and the first review I found says that the guitar the reviewer got was poorly aligned so that the tremolo block hits the body when divebombing, lifts the tremolo knife edge off its posts and puts guitar out of tune when it falls back in slightly different position.

Answer (score 1):

divebombing unloads the strings so much tension can be release all along their length - even beyond the nut and bridge pieces. When you bring the bridge back up to pitch, there is nothing to increase the tension beyond the nut back to where it was, so your strings end up at a lower pitch.

The best solution is a locking nut, which is why many brands have this option combined with a fully floating bridge. It needs to be locked securely so the strings cannot slip even a little.

Another solution is to pre-divebomb when tuning to allow the strings to settle somewhere predictable.

Comment: Tuning with a whammy bar & non-locked nut… the eternal dilemma. Dive to keep in tune, but then every time you bend it goes flat. Bend to keep in tune, then every dive goes flat. My solution was to remove the whammy & tighten the bridge solid ;))

Comment: One of my guitars has the Zero-Point trem, which is an attempt to fix this, but it doesn't feel as nice as a proper trem I can divebomb all day long

Comment: I only have a variety of 'standard' Strats, with their very primitive system. I couldn't even tell you where any of the whammy bars are these days. I think this is a habit i started in the 80s & haven't used one since ;)) My Variax is a hard-tail anyway.

Comment: I do happily use all the different trems for their different sounds (Kahler, Floyd-Rose, Strat etc) along with fixed bridge for more solid sustain and tone as needed. But my fave is the Ibanez Floyd Rose or my Joe Satriani special